# Got Documentation Beta invite, can't sign up

Tags: support, documentation

A few days ago, I received my invitation mail for the Documentation beta. It says the first step to sign up is "Create an account on the docs-beta site", with a link to http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/grant-beta-access?key=XXXXX. However, if I click the link, I only get this page without any option to actually sign up. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

[image: sign-up page]
(The log in and sign up tabs show the same content.)

Comment: That's strange. You should get "create new account" window.

Comment: Perhaps the link expires 24 hours after its created and sent to you?

Comment: Are you already logged in in the same browser/window/tab?

Comment: @cybermonkey The same happened a few hours after I got the mail, I only just got around to post this question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The first time I tried I wasn't, but the same happens if I am already logged in. (There is a "join this community"-Link in the top bar, but it also redirects to this page.)

Comment: @cyber Nope; I've used my two-month old invite and it worked. (signed up 3 days ago)

Comment: That's... weird. Joining a private beta is a pretty well-used process, so this sort of outright failure isn't expected or common. With the grant-beta-access key you should be able to either "join" (if you're already logged in) or "log in" (if you aren't). I'm not in a spot where I can dig through traffic logs just now, so... out of curiosity, what browser are you using? Any issues using or joining any other sites in the network? What's the "key" in your browser's address bar? I wonder if there's a period or something after it that's messing things up.

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts, perhaps logged into the wrong one?

Comment: @Adam I figured it out, will post it as an answer. The period led me to the right direction (i.e. double-checking the URL).

Comment: @anderas Great. Glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out what was the cause for my trouble: I use Firefox with the HTTPS Everywhere extension, so I usually browse SO via https. If I simply click the link in the mail, I get the described behaviour. But if I manually replace `http://` with `https://`, the link works fine and I can sign up.

*(I'm sorry I can't offer more details of where things went wrong. After the first time, I am obviously already signed up and can't try it again.)*